# Since, specifying a time point in the past

Tags: word-usage, present-perfect, past-perfect

I am a little confused on the correct usage of the word "since", in this case.

What is the best way to expressing hearing about something from some point in the past? For example:

> I had heard about you from your friends since last year!

That sounds a little strange.

> I have been hearing about you from your friends since last year!

That sounds correct, but I'm not entirely sure if it is.

What is wrong with these sentences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the first sentence:

> I **had heard** about you from your friends since last year!

This sentence is saying that at one point in time, you heard about a person. [Since](https://www.google.com/search?q=since+definition&rlz=1C1NHXL_enUS693US693&oq=since+definition&aqs=chrome..69i57.2658j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is a word that talks about some kind of passage of time.  This action ("had heard") did not happen over a period of time; it happened once and it wasn't continuous.

However, the second sentence seems to be correct, because it adds a sense that time had passed:

> I **have been hearing** about you from your friends since last year!

This verb tense explains that over some amount of time in the past, you heard about them, and this works with the word "since".

A way to fix the first sentence would be to remove "since".